# docker-php-entrypoint con python3 not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, docker, docker-compose

Estoy intentando montar un proyecto con python 3 usando djangorestframework, de manera autonoma sin docker corre bien, el problema es cuando intento dockerizarlo no se levanta me sacar el siguiente error

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint: 9: exec: python3: not found
```

este es mi *Dockerfile*

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app/api
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh \
    && ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh /
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 8000
```

tambien tengo otros servicios que funcionann correctamente al levantar el docker-compose , solo me falla el api con python

**docker-compose.yml**

```
    version: "3.1"

services:
  gui:
    image: node:14-alpine
    working_dir: /app
    command: "npm start"
    volumes:
      - ./gui:/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - api

  api:
    image: api
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=blog
      - POSTGRES_USER=zeus
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxxx
    depends_on:
      - db
      

  db:
    image: postgres:12
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - ./data/pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

requirements a nivel del  dockerfile

```
django==4.0.3
djangorestframework==3.13.1
```

para levantar los contenedores ejecuto

```
 sudo docker-compose up -d --build
```

todos levantan ecxepto api por el mismo problema

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En el command de tu api.
Deberías ejecutar el python sin el 3.

Comment: Ya lo deje solo con python  pero aun asi continua el  mismo error, el  docker-compose saca :command: python3 manage.py runserver   o si solo dejo python  :command: python manage.py runserver

Answer (score 0):

No sé cuál es el contenido de `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh`, pero probablemente intente ejecutar con python3, el archivo *python3* que, obviamente, no existe.

La solución pasa por cambiar el *command* de tu docker-compose a:

```
  api:
    image: api
    command: manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    entrypoint: /usr/bin/python3
```

También he añadido el entrypoint de python3, ya que no sabemos qué hace tu entrypoint personalizado.

Comment: Si no se ejecuta asi saca error:  /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint: 9: exec: manage.py: not found

Comment: Prueba a añadir lo siguiente debajo de ```command```: ```entrypoint: /usr/bin/python3```.
Lamentablemente, sin el docker-entrypoint, no vamos a poder ayudarte más.

Comment: docker-entrypoint este archivo no esta

Comment: basicamente no se que es ese entrypoint

Comment: Has probado a añadir la línea que te he indicado?

Comment: Si, saca este error:ERROR: for blog_api_1  Cannot start service api: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/usr/bin/python3": stat /usr/bin/python3: no such file or directory: unknown

ERROR: for api  Cannot start service api: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/usr/bin/python3": stat /usr/bin/python3: no such file or directory: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir en la pregunta qué comandos usas para compilar el Dockerfile?

Comment: lo puse al final

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir la línea ```build: ./dir``` debajo de command?
Cambia ./dir por la carpeta donde tengas el Dockerfile. Si lo tienes en la misma carpeta que el archivo de docker-compose, usa ```build: .```

Comment: lo puse pero no pasa del commadn con el mismo error :/usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint: 9: exec: manage.py: not found y si le dejo el pyhton3 /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint: 9: exec: python3: not found

Comment: Pues solo se me ocurre intentar ejecutar los comandos de compilación a mano. En la carpeta donde tengas los archivos: _docker build . api_ y, después, _docker-compose up -d_

Comment: me saca este Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "manage.py": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Comment: Prueba a cambiar el command a: ```command: /app/api/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000```

Answer (score 0):

Tanto mirar me di cuenta que faltaba el workdir en docker-compose por lo tanto no encontraba a python

```
api:
    image: api
    build: ./api
    working_dir: /var/www/
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

en el dockerfile tambien defini el workdir

```
WORKDIR /var/www
COPY ./ /var/www
EXPOSE 8000
```

Despues de hacerlo tuve que añadir otras extensiones en los requiremenmts

```
psycopg2==2.8.6
Pillow==9.0.1
```